# RubyMine Output Format

Tags: ruby

I'm afraid I'm a bit inexperienced with programming, and I am slowly coming to grips with coding in Ruby. I currently use the IDE RubyMine, and I am wondering how to separate different outputs by lines.
For example, if I put in

```
print 2 + 2
print 2 ** 5
print "foo"
```

How do I get the result to look like:

```
4
32
foo
```

rather than:

```
432foo
```

Answer (score 2):

`print` in Ruby doesn't output a line end character, but `puts` does:

```
puts 2 + 2
puts 2 ** 5
puts "foo"
```

Will give:

```
4
32
foo
```

`print` will only print newlines if you tell it to:

```
print "Hello!\n"
```

Is equivalent to:

```
puts "Hello!"
```